# Automate a particular state of an iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

Is there any way to store a particular state of an iPhone application. My objective is to make an application independent library which can be integrated into any application and which store the state of the application including events and corresponding time.This can be replayed from a particular section of the application.How can this be acheived? Hoping to get a healthy response.

Comment: I cannot think of any generic way of doing it.. For a single app  you can save the state to NSUserdefaults or something and get the data and  make the UI play using those data.

Comment: Yeah that's possible,but for that we need to track each action and event seperately. I need a way to track these without coding for each action so that the library can act independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging on that part I found the exact solution to my issue in the following link. http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/automated-user-interface-testing-on.html. Hope that helps somebody out there looking for solution for the same. However applications using the provided solution will be rejected by appstore. It can be used only for your own purposes.

Answer (score 1):

i think, It is not an generic way of doing it. because apple IOS SDK is not allow as to access other apps states information. but you may try private framework for it (In this case, App will not approve by apple).
thanks

Comment: Like Private Framework has bluetoothmanager class by which user can able to use bluetooth.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.I found the way of Implementing that. I have posted it above.

Answer (score 1):

Given that each application is intended to store and access data only within its sandbox (i.e., confined area of the file system), I suggest you look towards an external data source to store your library.

Specifically, could your requirements be met by iCloud storage? Some users may not have an active account, however, so an alternative may be to use a backend-as-a-service (BAAS) offering (e.g., Kinvey, StackMob, Parse)? You could store a user's profile and associated data on the latter. Or you could even roll your own backend as an external data source.

For info about the sandbox approach in iOS, check here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH9-SW2.

Hope that helps.

Comment: There are applications like FoneMonkey which is doing similar function and is primarily used for Automated Testing. Was hoping to come up with a similar functionality.I believe that's possible.